# Apache won't serve the directory and gives 403 Forbidden error

Tags: httpd, http-status-code-403

I've a folder that I want apache to serve. The folder is located under the `home` directory: `/home/mywebsite`.

This is my apache configuration file:

```
<Directory "/home/mywebsite">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<VirtualHost mywebsite.com:80>
        DocumentRoot "/home/mywebsite"
        ServerName "mywebsite"
</VirtualHost>
```

This is how the `home` directory looks like when I run the `ls -l` command.

```
total 1
drwxr-x--- 12 mywebsite     mywebsite     4096 Nov 20 15:05 mywebsite
```

I have no idea why I am getting 403 error. What is wrong with that configuration?

Comment: Is the user the webserver is running as (`www-data`, etc) a member of hte `mywebsite` group?  Also, are you on Apache2.2 or 2.4 ?

Comment: No, there is no a group www-data but I added `mywebsite` user to `apache` group.